# How to represent coordinates in pixels on a (limited) plan in Python

Tags: python, maps

I am terrible at these things so probably the question already exists and I could not find it.

From an API I receive a few points in a delimited perimeter (1 kilometer radius from my current position for now) that come as coordinates (extracted from Google maps, if it has any relevancy).
From that list of points I would like to show some dots on a map of pixels. I have drawn the map already, I have a few working variables already like 'center' and 'radius' (my map is a circle).
Now I want the radius of my circle (which is in pixels) to be equivalent to 1 kilometer of the Google maps coordinates (since I won't receive points further than that). And within my map I would like to place the pixels that represent the points proportionally to their position on the 'real' map within that range.

Are there any libraries that can help? What is the math for that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you have decimal coordinated like 50.3869881,-4.6177269 with north-south first.

As you have a fairly small size of map we don't need to worry about the curvature of the earth and we can assume we have a linear map so the (x,y) coordinates of the point on the map will be

```
x = longitude * a + b
y = latitude * c + d
```

where a, b, c, d are constants. The tricky bit is finding out what these constants are, which depend on what your latitude is.

One technique would be to use Google Earth which allows you to measure the distance between two point, you could say take two points with known coordinates and find the distance and bering between them. A little bit of high school geometry will give you the coordinates.

Another technique is to use the [Earth ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_ellipsoid) used by the map makers. These have 6,378,137m for the Equatorial radius and 6,356,752m for the Polar radius.

Still simpler take earth as a perfect sphere of radius 6,371,000m. Latitudes are easy, take a circle through both poles this will have circumference 2 pi r = 40,030km. Divide that by 360 and 1 degree of latitude = 111.2km. For longitude we need to do a little bit of trigonometry. A horizontal slice through the earth will have radius

```
6371km * cos(lat)
```

and 1 degree of longitude will be

```
6371km * 2 * pi * cos(lat) / 360
```

Some values of this are

```
 lat         dist
  0          111.2
 10          109.5
 20          104.5
 30           96.3
 40           85.2
 50           71.5
 60           55.6
 70           38.0
 80           19.3
 90           NA    things don't work at the poles
```

So to find coordinates. Let lat0, long0 are the coordinates of the point in the center of the circle and this is the point 0,0 on your map. Let lat1, long1 be point you want to find. First calculate `m = 6371km * 2 * pi * cos(lat0) / 360` then find the differences between the coords `dlat = lat1 - lat0`, `dlong = long1 - long0`. These are in degree so multiply by 111.2km and m to get distances in km. `x = dlong * m`, `y = dlat * 111.2`. This is only an approximation so things are only accurate to 1%.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I understand most parts but I am still confused at the part where we transfer the coordinates to pixels. I have tried implementing it as is and indeed I receive an x and y to print dots on my map. But yet I don't understand how to do the proportion. It covers way more than my 1 km radius, actually it's closer to 350km. Any idea how I can improve that?

Comment: One more thing, when the points on the real map move to the East then I see them moving to the left on my map. Any idea why it happens?

Comment: About that second comment, where I see the map upside down, I was adding the x and y to my center. Now that I am subtracting them I get the map correctly. But yet I don't know about the first comment, proportion.

Comment: The x and y values I've given above are in unit of 1 km. So without further scaling each pixel will be 1km wide. If `r` is desired radius of your circle in pixels and `R` is the radius in km then you will need to multiply by 'R/r' (or is it 'r/R').